# How do I allow site access on all sites for the LeechBlock extension in Incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to get [LeechBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/leechblock-ng/blaaajhemilngeeffpbfkdjjoefldkok) (a Chrome extension) to work in Incognito mode, and to do that, it needs to be able to read and change data on all sites.

However, once I allow the extension in Incognito, the site access resets to “on click”.

From there, I can change it to “on all sites”, but it changes back when I refresh or exit the page.

How can I permanently change the site access to “on all sites”?